# ORA-00911: invalid character error while executing a query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

`select salution||' '||firstname||' '||lastname as custName , city as custCity ,state as custState,zip as custZip,  dob as custDob ,idhardtoken as custAdarNo from mstuser   ;`

For the above query I am getting the oracle error ORA-00911: invalid character error while executing a query from java class file. What will be the correction for it ?

Comment: Was this query copied from a .doc or .docx file or something like that ?

Comment: Is this the actual query which caused the error?  I don't see any problem with the concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An SQL statement does not include a trailing semicolon. That is used as a statement separator in SQL*Plus and other clients (though even there you can change that to a different character), and it is not part of the statement itself. (PL/SQL requires semicolons as separators, but that's off-topic).

When you're running the statement over JDBC you should not include the semicolon. You should just be running

```
"select salution||' '||firstname||' '||lastname as custName, "
    + "city as custCity, state as custState, zip as custZip, "
    + "dob as custDob, idhardtoken as custAdarNo from mstuser"
```

(split just to show it without sideways scrolling...)

Comment: Thanks Alex for the knowledge you shared.